Writes to ceph rbd devices mapped on multiple nodes do not propagate until unmap
I am running an OpenShift environment backed by a Ceph service providing RBD block devices. When the same volume is mapped to multiple nodes (e.g., when using block volume mode), I'm seeing unexpected behavior: changes made to a volume aren't reflected on another nodes which are also mapping the same rbd volume.
Note: To avoid confusion, because there are a lot of people out there asking a different question, I am not attempting to mount a filesystem from these devices. I'm interacting directly with the block device.
For example, consider a PersistentVolumeClaim like this:
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: blockvol
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  volumeMode: Block
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi

This volume is mapped as a block device into multiple pods with the following deployment:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bvexample
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - blockvol
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      containers:
      - name: blockvol
        image: docker.io/python:3.12
        env:
        - name: NODE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 512Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 1Gi
        volumeDevices:
        - devicePath: /dev/blockvol
          name: blockvol
        command:
        - sleep
        - inf
      volumes:
        - name: blockvol
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: blockvol

When everything is up and running, we see pods running on two different nodes in the cluster:
$ kubectl get pod -l app=blockvol -o wide
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP              NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
bvexample-6f64cffc5f-5f5jc   1/1     Running   0          6m27s   10.128.17.189   wrk-29   <none>           <none>
bvexample-6f64cffc5f-k8bjr   1/1     Running   0          6m27s   10.131.17.137   wrk-35   <none>           <none>

The device is exposed as /dev/blockvol inside the pods:
$ kubectl get pod -l app=blockvol -o name |
  xargs -IPOD sh -c 'echo === POD ===; kubectl exec POD -- ls -l /dev/blockvol'
=== pod/bvexample-6f64cffc5f-5f5jc ===
brw-rw-rw-. 1 root disk 252, 16 Sep 25 01:09 /dev/blockvol
=== pod/bvexample-6f64cffc5f-k8bjr ===
brw-rw-rw-. 1 root disk 252, 16 Sep 25 01:09 /dev/blockvol

Initially, the device has only zeroes:
1000820000@bvexample-6f64cffc5f-k8bjr:/$ od -N16 -xa /dev/blockvol
0000000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000
        nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul
0000020

If I write data to this device, I would expect those changes to be visible immediately on other nodes. However, if in one pod I run:
1000820000@bvexample-6f64cffc5f-k8bjr:/$ echo this is a test. > /dev/blockvol
1000820000@bvexample-6f64cffc5f-k8bjr:/$ od -N16 -xa /dev/blockvol
0000000    6874    7369    6920    2073    2061    6574    7473    0a2e
          t   h   i   s  sp   i   s  sp   a  sp   t   e   s   t   .  nl
0000020

The other pod -- on a different node -- continues to see the original data:
1000820000@bvexample-6f64cffc5f-5f5jc:/$ od -N16 -xa /dev/blockvol
0000000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000
        nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul
0000020

If I kill the pods, forcing them to reschedule on new nodes:
$ kubectl delete pod -l app=blockvol

Then the changes will be visible on the block device in both locations:
=== pod/bvexample-6f64cffc5f-bkb5q ===
0000000    6874    7369    6920    2073    2061    6574    7473    0a2e
          t   h   i   s  sp   i   s  sp   a  sp   t   e   s   t   .  nl
0000020
=== pod/bvexample-6f64cffc5f-vv595 ===
0000000    6874    7369    6920    2073    2061    6574    7473    0a2e
          t   h   i   s  sp   i   s  sp   a  sp   t   e   s   t   .  nl
0000020

It looks like the rbd driver is caching changes locally until the rbd device is detached from a node, at which time the changes actually get written back to disk. Is this...regular behavior for rbd devices? A configuration setting of some sort? It was unexpected and means that the ReadWriteMany mode is effectively a lie (sure, you can write to it, but you can't actually read that data anywhere).

I'm not a k8s expert, but according to the docs ReadWriteMany is not covered by RBD. This is by design, there are a couple of other threads recommending to use CephFS if you nead ReadWriteMany.

You are looking at the wrong docs. Using cephfs covers a different situation (RWX file-based volumes, rather than raw block devices).

Hm, reading your link and following the link lists RBD as deprecated, but openstack cinder still seems to be supported. We use openstack with ceph as backend, and our k8s cluster runs on the cinder plugin. The cinder volumes have the multi-attach spec, so they can actually be attached to multiple pods. One of our customers uses cinder like that as well. Maybe that’s an option for you?
